# How can one perform color transforms with ICC profiles on a set of arbitrary pixel values (not on an image data structure)?

Tags: python, colors, python-imaging-library, color-space, color-profile

I'd like to convert a set of pixel values from one profiled colorspace to another, without these values residing in an image file, such as (say) a list of RGB/RGBA/CMYK/etc data structures.

I have Python and [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) at my disposal, but I'm interested in solutions in related environments if that's what it takes.

The latest PIL has very nice support for [LittleCMS](http://www.littlecms.com/) -- but no way to hand it anything other than a PIL image (or a legacy pyCMS object) for it to act upon.

As far as I can ascertain, the command-line tool `icctrans` that's included with LittleCMS does something of this sort, but I can't seem to find any non-skeletal documentation on it, and the documentation refers to it as a demonstration tool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to use the current 2.3 version of [Little CMS](http://www.littlecms.com/) with Python, I translated `lcms2.h` to `lcms2consts.py` with the `h2py.py` script that comes in the Python distribution. The script does not translate struct declarations, but the constants are enough to do basic color transformations with `ctypes` and `lcms2` as a dynamic library.

This example transforms a single colour from double precision Lab to 8-bit sRGB using built-in profiles. Use `cmsOpenProfileFromFile(filename, 'r')` instead for files.

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import byref
from lcms2consts import *

lcms = ctypes.windll.lcms2

inprof = lcms.cmsCreateLab4Profile(0)
outprof = lcms.cmsCreate_sRGBProfile()
xform = lcms.cmsCreateTransform(inprof, TYPE_Lab_DBL, 
    outprof, TYPE_RGB_8,
    INTENT_PERCEPTUAL, 0)
lcms.cmsCloseProfile(inprof)
lcms.cmsCloseProfile(outprof)

DblTriplet = ctypes.c_double * 3
ByteTriplet = ctypes.c_ubyte * 3
inbuf = DblTriplet(60.1,20.2,0.5)
outbuf = ByteTriplet()
lcms.cmsDoTransform(xform, byref(inbuf), byref(outbuf), 1)
print list(outbuf)

lcms.cmsDeleteTransform(xform)
```

Comment: I'd forgotten the question! That's a fantastic example, I found it quite useful (I ported it to cython to smooth out cross-platform dynamc-linking nits) but `h2py` is totally the Rosetta stone of Python extension programming. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways.

- **The hack way:** To reprofile N color structures (and/or transform them between colorspaces) you create a 1x(N+2) image with `PIL.Image.new()`, use `yourimage.load()` to get a pixel-setting object interface thing, and set values (0,0) through (0, N) to whatever you got. Set (0, N+1) to white and (0, N+2) to black, and transform (or proof-transform) that image using your favorite ICC files and `PIL.ImageCms.ImageCmsTransform()`. Blammo: that PIL object is now your LUT. Read the values off with the `image.load()` thingy and you're good.
- **The true-nerd way:** You need to use [Python-colormath](http://code.google.com/p/python-colormath/) -- which is great for colorspace transforms but not profiling. Colormath can't read ICC profiles, so either a) you get to parse their crazy binary format in a reliable way, or b) [just do the math](http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Math.html), literally. This guy Bruce Lindbloom has all the data available in excel format for, like, [all of the matricies](http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?WorkingSpaceInfo.html#ColorSets) you need to reprofile your LUTs. He is totally awesome. I am still trying to 'just' feed this data into colormath, so yeah, that makes me less awesome as I am still trying to get this 'nerd way' into something resembling production-quality.

There you go. That is what I did so far to answer the question of freestanding, commando-style ICC LUT transforms. U guys, srsly.

Comment: ever get any further with python-colormath?

Comment: @jedierikb I actually did – while it doesn't allow for general ICC profile transforms, if you have a way of reading some of the basic profile information, `python-colormath` will cover 90% of the math. It's a bit of a counterintuitive way to go as if feels like you're special-casing everything, until you realize that "general" ICC usage is pretty much a special-case in and of its own right – most frequently your math involves an XYZ matrix transform to or from sRGB values, and using a LUT in most other cases. I'm reading the profile using the ICCProfile class from http://dispcalgui.hoech.net