# Python PIL Imagine Library(CYMK Image Issue)

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, cmyk

I have diffrent color codes like #00FFFF,#FF00FF...

> im = Image.new("CMYK", (255, 100),str(color))

But it will always generate a "black" color image, Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (for this example i use "RGB", so replace the colors you want in rgb, should be similar with "CMYK"):

```
MAX_W, MAX_H = 350, 350
im = Image.new('RGB', (MAX_W, MAX_H), (238, 238, 238))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need CMYK image only to print!

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088375/how-can-i-convert-rgb-to-cmyk-and-vice-versa-in-python

Comment: yes i have tried also, but conversion generate little bit different image!i need pure CYMK image with color code