# PIL/Pillow decode icc profile information

Tags: python, encoding, python-imaging-library, color-profile

I am stuck with decoding/parsing ICC-profile information extracted with PIL.

Below a test image that contains the "Adobe RGB (1998)" profile.

```
# download the test image:
wget https://i.stack.imgur.com/62AHB.jpg
```

-

```
from PIL import Image
path = '62AHB.jpg'
icc = Image.open(path).info.get('icc_profile')
```

So far so good - but I could not find a way to handle returned ICC information.

The example above will return:

```
'\x00\x00\x020ADBE\x02\x10\x00\x00mntrRGB XYZ\x07\xcf\x00\x06\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00acspAPPL\x00\x00\x00\x00none\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\xf6\xd6\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\xd3-ADBE\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\ncprt\x00\x00\x00\xfc\x00\x00\x002desc\x00\x00\x010\x00\x00\x00kwtpt\x00\x00\x01\x9c\x00\x00\x00\x14bkpt\x00\x00\x01\xb0\x00\x00\x00\x14rTRC\x00\x00\x01\xc4\x00\x00\x00\x0egTRC\x00\x00\x01\xd4\x00\x00\x00\x0ebTRC\x00\x00\x01\xe4\x00\x00\x00\x0erXYZ\x00\x00\x01\xf4\x00\x00\x00\x14gXYZ\x00\x00\x02\x08\x00\x00\x00\x14bXYZ\x00\x00\x02\x1c\x00\x00\x00\x14text\x00\x00\x00\x00Copyright 1999 Adobe Systems Incorporated\x00\x00\x00desc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x11Adobe RGB (1998)\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00XYZ \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf3Q\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x16\xccXYZ \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00curv\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x023\x00\x00curv\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x023\x00\x00curv\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x023\x00\x00XYZ \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x9c\x18\x00\x00O\xa5\x00\x00\x04\xfcXYZ \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x004\x8d\x00\x00\xa0,\x00\x00\x0f\x95XYZ \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00&1\x00\x00\x10/\x00\x00\xbe\x9c'
```

How can this information be decoded?

There seem to be some *keys* inside the data. I basically would just need the value for *"desc"* which is  *"Adobe RGB (1998)"* in that case.

Any ideas? Looking forward for your inputs :) !

[image: Test image with embeded Adobe RGB (1998) profile]

Comment: Looks like a load of null bytes are in there and an ACK amongst others, you could use a regex to extract the info

Comment: This will clean it up `b" ".join(x for x in icc["icc_profile"].split(b"\x00") if x)`

Comment: I love that example image, brings back fond memories of a time gone... :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm writing this also for people that came here searching for information on how to process ICC color profile information in Python.

The [Pillow fork](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) of the original PIL library for Python includes a `ImageCms` module. Unfortunately the constructor for a profile requires a filename or a file-like object, so we have to do it sideways via [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO)

```
import io

from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageCms

image = Image.open('/tmp/DQ-Tool_Print_13x18cm.jpg')
icc = image.info.get('icc_profile')
f = io.BytesIO(icc)
prf = ImageCms.ImageCmsProfile(f)
```

Now `prf` contains a color profile instance. Have a look at the docs here: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageCms.html#PIL.ImageCms.CmsProfile

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know how to achieve this via png images?

Comment: To avoid digging: `print('model:', prf.profile.model)`.  Also if reading directly from a jpeg segment, need to skip 3 bytes past the header: `data[data.find(0)+3:]`

Comment: I've found `prf.profile.profile_description` more useful (sometimes `model` is `None`)

Answer (score 2):

I know this issue has been solved already, but I'm just adding this because it might be of some use to people who are looking for a way to extract ICC profile information in Python.

As part of the [jpylyzer](http://jpylyzer.openpreservation.org/) software (of which I'm the main developer), I once wrote some Python code for extracting the main header fields of an ICC profile (this is completely independent of any external libraries). See the *validate_icc* function below:

https://github.com/openpreserve/jpylyzer/blob/master/jpylyzer/boxvalidator.py#L598

If you follow [this link](http://jpylyzer.openpreservation.org//userManual.html#colour-specification-box) and then scroll down a bit, you'll see an overview of all the reported properties. Note that the code does not actually read the information inside the ICC tags, but you could extend it based on the [ICC profile specifications](http://www.color.org/icc_specs2.xalter).

Comment: thanks for the information. so we know where to look the next time :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a dedicated Python module that can handle [ICC color profiles](http://www.color.org/faqs.xalter#profiles).

If you feel adventurous, take a look at section 6 *"Requirements"* of the [ICC Profile Format Specification](http://www.color.org/icc32.pdf). This should get you started on how to interpret the bytes.

Pillow's [test folder](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/tree/master/Tests) contains two ICC profiles though, so perhaps it is worthwhile digging through the code of some of their tests. You might also want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597528/how-can-one-perform-color-transforms-with-icc-profiles-on-a-set-of-arbitrary-pix#9375166) which refers to [Little CMS](http://www.littlecms.com/) that seems to have some ICC profile support.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We did finally solve this using an external tool [exiftool](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) and extracting the icc information form a subprocess call.